# Gnome Keyring password prompt does not move, is it normal?

Tags: skype, gnome-keyring

When opening Skype, Gnome Keyring password prompt does not move, is it expected behavior, in Xubuntu 20.10, Skype downloaded and installed in December, 27? I googled for "gnome keyring password prompt does not move" and similar queries (e.g. "gnome keyring dialog not movable"), and answer is not visible.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David added to the question, because comment "@David 20.10" was too short to submit

Comment: Since terminal I/O is "full duplex", when reading a password, the program has 3 choices: output the typed password (vulnerable to "shoulder surfing");read 1 character at a time and output a fixed character, e.g. "`*`", for each password character; output nothing. Does the password "work"? Does a bad password fail?

Comment: That info should always be in a question.

Comment: @waltinator it is not on my computer, it is hard to check, whether bad pasword fails. i do not understand, why you wrote the text before that. it is gui, you wrote about terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is normal, according to [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-keyring/-/issues/73):

> The initial Gnome Keyring password prompt is modal when logging in, so
> that would not be a bug